# How to display content of javascript source file?

Tags: javascript

How to display content of javascript source file? I have the url of the source file. I just want to display it in a text area and alert box. No matter the size of the file.

```
<pre>function getFile() {  
  var url = "http://example.com/s/js/file.js";
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    //code for IE7+, FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    //code for IE5,IE6
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function redraw()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</pre>
```

Comment: You're looking for AJAX.

Comment: If the file is on the same domain, you can use AJAX to get its text.  If not, you're gonna need a server-side proxy script to return the text.

Comment: You can grab it with an ajax request or preload it server side before the page creation.

Comment: Actually what is my expectation is, I have one server side js file. I need to take some information from that file. I have the url i.e. location of the js file in the server. when I hit the url in browser then I am getting response. But when I am trying above code, it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$.get("file.js", function(file) {
    $("textarea").val(file);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: [Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)